# I dropped a thumb tack down the drain, should I be worried?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

It’s a small plastic one like you would use to hang a poster or calendar. Sink drain

Comment: It'll probably be fine once it gets into the big 2"+ drain, but if it gets stuck before then, it'll catch more stuff and create a clog.  How are you at taking apart traps?  (it's a skill that is good for ring wearers to have).

Comment: "the drain"? Most bathrooms have 3 - sink, tub/shower, toilet. Which one?

Comment: If it can fit down the strainer width-wise, no problem. Length-wise, like a q-tip; that's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I can't imagine it doing any harm and it's not worth the effort to remove the trap to try and find it as it probably has already passed the trap and is in the sewer. 
If you like to fish, you could fasten a magnet to a piece of string and lower in into the drain and try to snag the tack. Just don't lose the magnet down there. You could also remove the trap but that can be messy and why take it apart if it's not leaking.

Comment: A trap, which is not leaking, which is taken apart, will never again not leak  :O

Comment: Downside of a magnet on a string is that it may drop, get stuck to something ferrous, and will not flush away.   And its also possible the tack isn't ferrous anyway so the magnet may not attract it.  OP says its plastic but that's probably not the sharp pin, which might be stainless steel and therefore not magnetic.

Comment: Stainless steel is magnetic. Or better, is attracted by magnets.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a sewage pump I can't see it being a problem. Maybe if your line is already clogged enough to be a problem.

Comment: Eviscerator pump owners beware, +1